# IOS swift 3 UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

How to select UITableView row Data that is selected programatically.

Eg. I develop like this for selecting

```
self.tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated:true, scrollPosition: .middle)
```

And for get row data I used

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

}
```

I didn't get the result.

Answer (score 0):

set following in your viewDidLoad

```
 tableView.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by this:

```
func getCell(row: Int, section: Int) -> CellClassName {
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:row, inSection: section)
        let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CellClassName!
        return selectedCell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614875-selectrow):

> Calling this method does not cause the delegate to receive a [`tableView(_:willSelectRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614943-tableview) or [`tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614877-tableview) message, nor does it send [`UITableViewSelectionDidChange`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification.name/1614958-uitableviewselectiondidchange) notifications to observers.

So your delegate method won't be called. But if you're calling that method you already have the index path of the selected element, so you can process it like you are already doing in your delegate method.

For example:

```
var elements: [String] = []
var selectedElement: String?

var tableView: UITableView!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedElement = elements[indexPath.row]
}

func selectElement(element: String) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: elements.index(of: element), section: 0)
    selectedElement = element
    tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .middle)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you look for is defined in `Managing Selections` section in [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview):

- [var indexPathForSelectedRow: IndexPath?](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1615000-indexpathforselectedrow)

An index path identifying the row and section of the selected row.

- [var indexPathsForSelectedRows: [IndexPath]?](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614864-indexpathsforselectedrows)

The index paths representing the selected rows.